# JSX and v8js - Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, v8

Right, so I'm trying to work out the kinks in my code for working with rendering react JSX code on the server side.

When my `test.js` is as follows:

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({displayName: 'CommentBox',
    render: function() {
        return (
            React.createElement(
                'div', 
                {className: "commentBox"},
                "Hello, world! I am a CommentBox."
            )
        );
    }
});
```

The following code works:

```
    $react_source = implode("\n", [
        file_get_contents(\Yii::getAlias("@bower").'/react/react.js'),
        file_get_contents(\Yii::getAlias("@bower").'/react/react-dom-server.js'),
    ]);

    $react_app = implode("\n", [
        file_get_contents(\Yii::getAlias("@app").'/web/test/test.js')
    ]);

    $react = array();
    // stubs, react
    $react[] = "var console = {warn: function(){}, error: print}";
    $react[] = "var global = global || this, self = self || this, window = window || this";
    $react[] = $react_source;
    $react[] = "var React = global.React";
    $react[] = "var ReactDOMServer = global.ReactDOMServer";
    $react[] = $react_app;

    $concatenated = implode(";\n", $react);

    $v8 = new \V8Js();

    $v8->executeString($concatenated);

    $js = $v8->executeString(sprintf("ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(%s))", 'CommentBox'));

    return $this->render('index', [
        'js' => $js
    ]);
```

But when my `test.js` looks like the following:

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="commentBox">
                Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

I get the following error: `V8Js::compileString():18861: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Now I'm assuming this is because the JSX code needs to be compiled into the javascript code (the working version), but how do I go about doing that on the back end side with PHP?

**SUCCESS... Kind of**
So I managed to get this working. I used babel to convert the file from jsx to normal js, which looks like my original working code. This all works nicely with the PHP side rendering. However, now I'm having issues with getting webpack bundled code to work correctly, but that's another issue, so I'm going to close this.

Comment: I think, you have to enclose it with single quotes like `return ('<div className="commentBox">Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.</div>');` in **test.js**.

Comment: @NanaPartykar - I've tried that and it doesn't work - I then get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Comment: @NanaPartykar Nope, I don't think you know what JSX is..

Comment: Yes. I don't know. You are correct @usandfriends.

Comment: @SynackSA Look at [Babel for JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html#productionizing-precompiled-jsx) and [this](https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/02/23/babel-loves-react).

Comment: @usandfriends - So I have to pre-compile everything with browserify/webpack/etc into another js file and then use that file?

Comment: You don't need to concat all the files. Just run JSX transformer on your `.jsx` files.

Answer (score 0):

Some processors require you use the `.jsx` extension.

Try renaming `test.js` to `test.jsx`when you are using the angled bracket notation.

EDIT: And rename in your code obviously